# C# Task - Aggregate exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, task

With below code Im trying to update customer model on cache & sql db asynchronously. Either one of the tasks or both tasks may fail & it will leads to AggregateException.

In the AggregateException I want to know which exception related to which task. Lets say inside AggregateException, I have Exception1 & Exception2. Want to know Exception1 originated by  "updateCacheCustomerTask" failure while Exception2 originated by  "updateDBCustomerTask" failure. How to do that? please suggest.

```
   public async Task UpdateCustomerAsync(T model)
    {
        var updateCacheCustomerTask = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            throw new Exception();
        });

        var updateDBCustomerTask = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            throw new Exception();
        });

        await Task.WhenAll(updateCacheCustomerTask , updateDBCustomerTask ).ContinueWith(result =>
        {
            if (result.Exception != null)
            {
                throw result.Exception;
            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do `throw new Task1Exception(msg, ex);` in one, and `throw new Task2Exception(msg, ex)` in the other. You'll need to define as many Task...Exception classes as you have Tasks, with the needed constructor.

Passing in `ex` means that `InnerException` is set to the actual Exception that occurred, captured if needed using a try-catch.

You can also do `throw new Exception(msg, ex);` in all Tasks, so without using custom Exception classes, but then you'll need to make sure that you can distinguish the instances using the contents of the `msg` values.